shared vs exclusive lock in sql for each isolation level
I am studying transaction in sql, i read about isolation levels. Got to know about shared lock(read lock) and exclusive lock(write lock).
As per multiple sources, exclusive lock can only be taken if there is no lock on same row.
Multiple shared lock can be placed on same row.
Below is my understanding of locking in each isolation level.

I totally understood what problem each isolation level solves but unable to understand locking behaviour in each isolation level.
=====================================================
session 1
set session transaction isolation level serializable;
BEGIN;
SELECT * from film where film_id=13; --shared lock taken

session 2
set session transaction isolation level <any-isolation-level>;
BEGIN;
SELECT * from film where film_id=13; --able to read. understandable. multiple shared lock can be taken
update film set title = "Monkey Busineess3" where film_id=13; --keeps loading until session1 commit. understandable. cannot take exclusive lock over shared lock

========================================================
session 1
set session transaction isolation level <any isolation level>;
BEGIN;
SELECT * from film where film_id=13 for update; -- exclusive lock taken

session2
set session transaction isolation level <any-isolation-level>;
BEGIN;
select * from film where film_id=13; --able to read. how? exclusive lock exists. shared lock cannot be taken over exclusive
update film set title = "Monkey Busineess3" where film_id=13; --keeps loading until session1 commit. understandbale since exclusive lock is taken

============================================================
session 1
set session transaction isolation level repeatable read;
BEGIN;
SELECT * from film where film_id=13; -- shared lock taken

session 2
set session transaction isolation level <any-isolation-level>;
BEGIN;
update film set title = "Monkey Busineess3" where film_id=13; --able to update. how? exclusive lock cannot be taken over shared lock

============================================================
After doing multiple such query on my local mysql. I can conclude that,
if shared lock  is taken then other transaction can read and write same row except in seriablizable isolation level.
but if exclusive lock is taken other transaction can read but cannot write.
If this is true then why take shared lock at all? since other transaction can still read and write over same row except in seriablizable isolation level.
I asked chatgpt and it says this is something because of mvcc. Mysql maintains multiple version of same row at transaction level so over shared lock as well other transactions can still write.
I am having problem co-relating locking, isolation level and mvcc so can anyone explain what is actual behaviour and corelation between
lock, isolation level and mvcc with example or refer to any article that explains it

If a row is locked in any way, you cannot update or delete it as any modification requires exclusive lock, which is incomoatible with any other locks. Repeatable read does not set shared locks without setting it explicitly for a select. That's serialisable isolation level.
